# Comparing two dates- String was not recognised as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Im trying to compare the current date with the Date from the date time picker.The control shows the date like this

[image]

Im comparing the two dates like this

```
 DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(dtInvoiceDate.Text);
            DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
            if (dt2.Date > dt1.Date)
            {

                dgvGetData.Columns["Edit"].Visible = false;
            }
```

But this is throwing a ***String was not recognised as a valid DateTime Exception.***

How can i parse the Date in this short format and compare.

Comment: Can't you read any other property from dtInvoiceDate control other than `Text` ? Isnt any `value` property w/type DateTime ? (so you can avoid parsing)

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli Which property specifically? There is no property called `Date` as such.

Comment: Did you tried 'Value' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not parse the DateTime. The Date Picker control **must** provide you the date as a  `DateTime`. Try:

```
DateTime dt1 = dtInvoiceDate.Value;
```

Comment: I think MS could add a property called DateTime rather than Value..Its confusing ...

Comment: When they released winforms, those old good days, there was like a standard that every control must have a Value property. It makes sense to me. Try to avoid `.Text` as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Gerado, you shouldn't parse Date picker, also you could add **ValueChanged** property to your DTP control which is often useful. Whenever the user changes the *DateTime*, this event handler is executed.

```
DateTime date = dateTimePickerCheck.Value;
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (date.Date > now.Date)
{
     //your code logic
}
```